# Correct way to do client notification event with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm working on a chat app in react native which uses socket.io

Chat rooms only have two persons.

On my node server app, when first user joins chat `socket.on('joinRoom')` trigger an emit `io.to("room123").emit("notifyTo"+userTwoId), response)` to notify the second user.

On my React native app, I have this event: `socket.on("notifyTo"+currentUserId)` to notify to current user that user one has joined the chat.

My question is, is this approach correct? regarding the use of the user id to be able to broadcast (from the server) and capture the event (from the client)

Comment: It's probably better for your event nae to be generic (Without any ids) and use the event body to send any data.

Comment: Or just send the message to the specific user you want it to be sent to.  It's wasteful to be broadcasting messages to clients that don't need them or aren't listening for that message name.